# Three divs, middle scrollable and auto-fill content

Tags: css, html

I have three divs vertically stacked. Header, content and footer.
All of them have width set to 100% of the page width.
Header and footer have a defined height (let's say 75px).

I'm trying to make the content div to be pushed up by the footer and make it fill all the space left in between. (if the footer becames invisble the content div will also fill that gap)

[image: Header, content and footer divs]

How can I do this?.
Thanks.

This is the code I have so far.

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header" style="background-color: orange;width: 100%;height: 75px;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;"></div>
        <div id="content" style="background-color: gray;width: 100%;height:100%;overflow: visible;"></div>
        <div id="footer" style="background-color: red;width: 100%;height: 75px;position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish I understood what you were asking!!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enought. Using three divs I want to accomplish what's described in the image above. I can make the header and footer divs take their positions but I cannot make the Content div to fill all the space left on the page by the other two. Is there a way of doing this only with html-css or do I need to use javascript also?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position it absolutely, and say "go from 75px at the top, to 75px from the bottom."

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JcAdV/)

---

Without modifying anything else in your code, the `#content` div will be styled like this.

```
#content {
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 75px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In case the footer is set to display:none then I would have to change the bottom to 0px. Is there a way of doing this without the need of javascript? I mean not setting the bottom and that I gets automatically pushed up by the footer.

Comment: Under what cirmstances would the footer be not displayed?  If it's not with JS, the only other case I can think of would be editing the CSS.  So you could set display to none and the content's bottom to 0.  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v76S7/)

Comment: There are two cases when the footer is not displayed. 1 When the div is not part of the html. 2. When the user chose to "close" it. I understand the 2nd involves JS to make the footer go away but I was wondering if I also have to set the bottom (or width) of the content or if this can be done without the need of JS.

Comment: Ok.  So if you're using JS in the second example, I think you can handle it with JS there.  If you're going to be changing the HTML, you can make a `noFooter` class and add that to the content div.  [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JcAdV/1/).  If there is going to be a footer: remove that class.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible but I think you should use CSS3 for it.

You first need to set the height of all parent elements to 100% too.

Than you need to set `box-sizing` to `border-box` because you need to set the padding top after. You set the padding top because you don't want to have hidden text under the header.

CSS3 box-sizing example:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-icab-box-sizing: border-box;
-khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UcgYT/1/) example.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem I see with this is that the footer gets on top of the content.